# Renaming rows according to a separate index

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, bioinformatics

I'm currently working with a matrix that looks like this:

```
gene ID    untreated_1 merb_2h_1 merb_4h_1 merb_8h_1
1            2.961344  2.656308  3.322758  3.201053
100          3.998061  3.860054  3.934714  3.069164
1000         8.987753  9.125033  9.220713  9.141715
10000        8.165543  7.973907  7.472961  7.361228
10001       4.8865396  4.641879  4.523251  3.411761
100033431   0.5847026  1.347103  1.203390  1.550687
```

I would like to change the gene ID column for their equivalent name under the hgnc nomenclature which I have already listed on the gene annotation table below:

```
       gene ensembl_gene_id hgnc_symbol
1         1 ENSG00000121410 A1BG
2        10 ENSG00000156006 NAT2 
3       100 ENSG00000196839 ADA  
4      1000 ENSG00000170558 CDH2 
5     10000 ENSG00000117020 AKT3
6 100008586 ENSG00000224659 GAGE12J 
7 100009676 ENSG00000256628 ZBTB11-AS1
```

Note only some of the genes of the annotation table are present in the matrix I'm working with. My question is then how to rename the gene ID column from the matrix I'm working with, by the hgnc nomenclature I have on the separate gene annotation list. I'm working with a really big matrix, so I guess I need some parallel task.

Comment: You could use `match` - `df1$geneID <- df2$hgnc_symbol[match(df1$geneID,df2$gene)]`

Comment: Do you know about `merge`?

Comment: Sorry Aaghaz I don't know, I'm quite new on R

Comment: I agree with AndrewGustar's approach, but will add that matrices in R can only take one data type, and the $ operator can't be used on them. To use their solution, convert your original matrix to a data frame using as.data.frame().

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
df1$geneID <- df2$hgnc_symbol[match(df1$geneID,df2$gene)]
```